# How to call selected option php variable, that was set using jquery, by jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to call the selected value from the option by using JQuery but it keeps on passing the default value only. The option select was set using JQuery as when the edit button is pressed, the field changes to select.

i have tried this :

```js
$("#tstSelected option").filter(":selected").val();
```

and this:

```
$( "#tstSelected option:selected" ).text();
```

and none seemed to work

```js
if($(this).hasClass('fa-pencil')){
          $.each(currentTD, function () {
            if($(this).hasClass('editable')){
              if($(this).hasClass('getFromSelect')){
                //$(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
                $(this).html("<select>" + "<?php foreach($test as $tst){ echo "<option id='tstSelected' value='$tst->tst_idx'>". $tst->tst_desc . $tst->tst_idx ."<option>"; } ?>" + "</select>");

              }
              $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
            }
          });
          $(this).removeClass('fa-pencil')
              .addClass('fa-check')
              editing = true;
        }
```

then I'm calling the selected value like this:

```js
$("#tstSelected option").filter(":selected").val();
```

but it's not working

I am just getting the default value only which is the value of the first selected value

Answer (score 2):

Try to give id to `select` Tag:

```
 if($(this).hasClass('fa-pencil')){
          $.each(currentTD, function () {
            if($(this).hasClass('editable')){
              if($(this).hasClass('getFromSelect')){
                //$(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
                $(this).html("<select id= 'select_tag'>" + "<?php foreach($test as $tst){ echo "<option id='tstSelected' value='$tst->tst_idx'>". $tst->tst_desc . $tst->tst_idx ."<option>"; } ?>" + "</select>");

              }
              $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
            }
          });
          $(this).removeClass('fa-pencil')
              .addClass('fa-check')
              editing = true;
        }
```

Take value of selected option as below:

```
$("#select_tag").val();
```

Comment: this works perfectly... Thank you very much I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You're try to find the `option` tag inside the `option` tag.

```
// Here #tstSelected seems to already be a <option>
// "<option id='tstSelected' ... >"
$("#tstSelected option").filter(":selected").val();

// Add id on <select> instead of <option> and use this. 
$("#tstSelected").val();
```

Here is the changes you need to do in your php.

```php
$(this).html("<select id='tstSelected'>" + "<?php foreach($test as $tst){ echo "<option value='$tst->tst_idx'>". $tst->tst_desc . $tst->tst_idx ."<option>"; } ?>" + "</select>");
```

Comment: What is undefined ?

Comment: When I did the changes that you said, I tried to alert the value and it is showing that the value is undefined

Comment: So try only with `$("#tstSelected").val();`